# Props passed to child component is undefined but console.log shows props' value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, carousel, react-props

I try to create Carousel in my app based on Gatsby. I have a issue with passing props from Parent to Child functional component. I get error ***TypeError: props.slide is undefined*** 
[image]but when I check logs in console, then I can see that the props.slide has value 
[image]

I only wonder about 1st line int the console (screenshot above) which shows empty props, right?
Odd thing is codesandbox doesn't give any error: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-snyder-9hjpf

The Parent component:

```
//imports...

const carouselItems = [
  {
    title: "Laser scanning",
    picture: "../../../../assets/images/RTC360.png",
    content:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A ad deserunt, enim est exercitationem facilis illum ipsum iure, mollitia placeat quia temporibus voluptatem. Asperiores assumenda id nesciunt totam. Eligendi, neque."
  },
  {
    title: "Mobile mapping",
    picture: "../../../../assets/images/RTC360.png",
    content:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A ad deserunt, enim est exercitationem facilis illum ipsum iure, mollitia placeat quia temporibus voluptatem. Asperiores assumenda id nesciunt totam. Eligendi, neque."
  }
];

interface CarouselState {
  activeIndex: number;
}

class Carousel extends React.Component<any, CarouselState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activeIndex: 0
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {carouselItems.map((slideDescription, index) => (
            <CarouselDescriptionRCTypes
              key={index}
              index={index}
              activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex}
              slide={slideDescription}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Carousel;
```

The child component:

```
//imports...

interface CarouselDescriptionProps {
  index: number;
  activeIndex: number;
  slide: {
    title: string;
    picture: string;
    content: string;
  };
}

const CarouselDescriptionRCTypes: React.FC<
  CarouselDescriptionProps
> = props => {

  if (!props) {
    return null;
  }

  console.log(`props${JSON.stringify(props)}`);
  console.log(`props.slide.title${props.slide.title}`);

  return (
    <div>
      <strong className="carousel-slide__author">{props.slide.title}</strong>
      <small className="carousel-slide__source">{props.slide.content}</small>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CarouselDescriptionRCTypes;
```

Comment: The first line of your log shows props as an empty array I guess that is when you get an error. Looking at the code I don't see any reason for it to be an empty. Is your example exactly the same as the code you are having issue with?

Comment: It works fine, you add `<CarouselDescriptionRCTypes />` without props to your `IndexPage` so that is where you get the error, and your guard clause `if(!props)` does not work since props is an object always, so you need to check each prop separately or use something like lodash `_.isEmpty`, or `!Object.keys(props).lenght`

Comment: Thank you @Shlang! That works! That make sense to me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Shlang answered my question.
I have been checking props in IF clause by

```
 if (!props) {
    return null;
  }
```

which always return true because props is always object and will never be undefined. I believed that checking props will prevent return undefined error which is wrong.

As @Shlang mentioned it should be checked every value in props by the same clause like:

```
if (!props.slide) {
    return null;
  }
```

, or by using e.g. Lodash library with its isEmpty function.